# Argparser with default value and required

Tags: python, subparsers

I try to build an argparser, where one of the parsers should have a default value, and is also a required.
I have the following so far:

```
   fulllist_parser.add_argument(
    '--type',
    required=True,
    default="VirtualMachine",
    type=str,
    help='Object type, e.g. Network, VirtualMachine.'
```

When I run it from CLI, I get an error:

```
 supdeploy fulllist: error: argument --type is required
```

I see why this is coming up, as I'm not including `--type` on the CLI.
And that is what I want to achieve, that the default is set even if I don't include the parser option on CLI.

Anyway to run this?

Comment: Aren't "required" and "has a default value" mutually exclusive? "the user absolutely must supply a value for this, crash otherwise" vs "if the user does not supply a value for this, that's fine, just use this value"

Comment: Doh ;) Why did I not think about it. Thanks for the hint, exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, maybe not exactly. As I will not see the help output anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `default` and no `required`

```
fulllist_parser.add_argument(
  '--type',
  default="VirtualMachine",
  type=str,
  help='Object type, e.g. Network, VirtualMachine.'
```

Because then if it isn't specified you get the default value back (so you always get a value). Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html#default):

> The default keyword argument of add_argument(), whose value defaults to None, specifies what value should be used if the command-line argument is not present. For optional arguments, the default value is used when the option string was not present at the command line